# Error Inflating Class/View

Tags: android, android-view, android-inflate

I know there are many other questions asked about errors inflating the view, but none of the answers have seemed to help me.  I have a custom view called DrawableView in my class Notepad.

```
public class Notepad extends Activity {
    ...
    public class DrawableView extends View {
        public DrawableView(Context c) {
            super(c);
            setup();
        }

        public DrawableView(Context c, AttributeSet as) {
            super(c,as);
            setup();
        }

        public DrawableView(Context c, AttributeSet as, int ds) {
            super(c,as, ds);
            setup();
        }
    }
}
```

Then my xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <view class="com.acuitus.main.Notepad$DrawableView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </view>
</LinearLayout>
```

and it is causing the error

```
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.acuitus.testlayouts/com.acuitus.main.Notepad}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.acuitus.main.Notepad$DrawableView
...
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.acuitus.main.Notepad$DrawableView
...
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
```

Full error stack is below if you really want it

```
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745): Process: com.acuitus.testlayouts, PID: 16745
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.acuitus.testlayouts/com.acuitus.main.Notepad}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.acuitus.main.Notepad$DrawableView
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.acuitus.main.Notepad$DrawableView
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:603)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1937)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at com.acuitus.main.Notepad.onCreate(Notepad.java:36)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    ... 11 more
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:446)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:568)
06-24 10:05:44.338: E/AndroidRuntime(16745):    ... 22 more
```

I am confused by it saying I don't have the method for the AttributeSet when I clearly do. Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare View class as a static or make it in another file...even better.